# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Below is the error message i get for the code i have written. I have mention the code after the error message. I am new and need help!!

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {angular.min.js:6
>
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3A…A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8084%2FAngularProject%2FLib%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:38m
>   @ angular.min.js:7g @ angular.min.js:37eb @ angular.min.js:40d @
>   angular.min.js:19Ac @ angular.min.js:20Zd @
>   angular.min.js:18(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:289a @
>   angular.min.js:176c @ angular.min.js:35"

```
<script src="Lib/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Lib/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            var demoApp=angular.module('mainApp',[ngRoute]);

            demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                        .when('/',
                {
                    controller:'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl:'view1.html'
                })
                        .when('/view1',{
                            controller:'SimpleController',
                            templateUrl:'/view.html'
                })
                        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
            });

            demoApp.controller('SimpleController',function($scope){
            $scope.customers=[
            {name:'Joe',city:'Toronto'},
            {name:'Jane',city:'Sydney'},
            {name:'Roberto',city:'Vienna'},
            {name:'Kumiko',city:'Japan'}
           ];

           $scope.addCustomer=funtion(){
             $scope.customers.push({name:$scope.newCustomer.name,city:$scope.newCustomer.city});  
           };
        });/*
            function SimpleController($scope){
                $scope.customers=[
                    {name:'Sabin',city:'Bhaktapur'},
                    {name:'Abhi',city:'Lalitpur'},
                    {name:'shree',city:'Kathmandu'},
                    {name:'rameshwor',city:'Bhojpur'}
                   ];
            }*/
        </script>
```

Comment: You should click on the link the error provides and read what the page says. Copy the link if the link is broken in the console

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle/plunkr ?

Answer (score 3):

`ngRoute` should be in quotes:

```
var demoApp=angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: I did it with quote but still does not work. here is the message i get.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3A…A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8084%2FAngularProject%2FLib%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)

Comment: Please add a code snippet/fiddle, it'll be easier to debug.