# Angularjs Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying simply read qr code by web camera but I get this error in console open angular help page but saying using ngRoute

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=q...)
```

angular and html code here

```
<html ng-app="App">
<body ng-controller="qrCrtl">
<qr-scanner width="400" height="300" ng-success="onSuccess(data)" ng-error="onError(error)" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script data-main="qr-scanner.js" src="require.js"></script>
<script src="src/jsqrcode-combined.min.js"></script>
<script>
var App = angular.module('App', ['qrScanner']);
   App.controller('qrCrtl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.onSuccess = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    };
    $scope.onError = function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    };
    $scope.onVideoError = function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    };
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you added the full error rather than the truncated one.

Comment: You are probably having an issue retrieving the `qr-scanner.js` script. Also, is [Angular-qr-scanner](http://sembrestels.github.io/angular-qr-scanner/) the library in question? Some more detail would be helpful

Comment: I used this example by git repo

Comment: @kakashihatake: can you post the link of that repo? can you make a punk? more details about the error as sg.cc suggested ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you did not inject the ngRouter library into your module, like so,

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['qrScanner', 'ngRoute']);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900954/uncaught-error-injectormodulerr-http-errors-angularjs-org-1-4-3-injector) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Also, make sure that you import the Angular route library after angular, like so,

```
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
```